# How do I convert a 4-drive BTRFS raid1 to a 2-drive "single" (non-raid) mode

Tags: btrfs

I have 4 equal-sized drives in a BTRFS raid1 configuration. I would like to free up two of the drives for use in a different system.

I'm pretty confident that this is possible with BTRFS, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it properly.

I have all of the data backed up elsewhere FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly tested this procedure on a scratch filesystem made of four small LVM logical volumes. The first question is do you want to keep it mirrored (with reduced capacity) or not?

In all of the below, `«PATH»` is the mountpoint of your btrfs filesystem. These are online operations.

**If you do not want the data mirrored** (because it won't fit with the reduced capacity, for example):

- Get rid of the mirror, converting the filesystem to how it would be without it. By default, that's duplicated metadata and a single copy of data. However, since you have two disks still, raid1 metadata makes much more sense. You do this with a rebalance. The "soft" here means to only convert block-groups which need it—e.g., metadata that is already raid1 won't be touched. (Same with data that is already "single", which could happen if you canceled this partway through and start it again later).

  ```
    btrfs balance start -mconvert=raid1,soft -dconvert=single,soft «PATH»
  ```

Balance will (by default) run in the foreground; you can give `--background` to get your terminal back (and check the status with `btrfs balance status «PATH»`). Status messages will also be printed to dmesg (and thus the kernel log and/or systemd journal). This will probably take a good long while; btrfs loves moving data around ☹.

**Next up, tell btrfs to stop using the disks**. You do this whether you've left it mirrored or not.

- Now you can remove the other two disks from the btrfs filesystem. This will also move a bunch of data and thus take a while. Note that you can (and should) remove both disks at once, otherwise it might move data onto the disk you want to remove next.

  ```
    btrfs device remove /dev/disk1 /dev/disk2 «PATH»
  ```

Notice the disk/partition devices go before the mount point. Again this is an online operation. You can watch status in the kernel log.

When this is finished, you can remove the disks from the system.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there might be some way to do it all in one go, but this will do. Now just kick back and wait a few days...